# Sitecore 8.2 error for path analyzer

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, sitecore8.2

I have upgraded sitecore from sitecore 8.1 to sitecore 8.2. For Path Analyzer I m getting following error:

```
DeployDate

Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: DeployDate

Source Error: 


Line 53: 
Line 54:   var mapListBuilder = new               MapListBuilder(ApplicationContainer.GetMapStatusService(), ApplicationContainer.GetConfiguration().ContentDatabaseName);
Line 55:   var mapListData = mapListBuilder.Build();
Line 56:   rendering.Attributes.Add("data-sc-maplistdata", mapListData);
Line 57: 

Source File:   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreSolr\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\PathAnalyzer\Common\App.cshtml
```

Am I missing some file to add?

Comment: I just bumped into the same problem. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Another guy with the same issue here. Did this ever get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when upgrading a Sitecore site to version 8.2.

As part of the upgrade I had to create a secondary reporting database and run a rebuild on the reporting database.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--rebuilding-the-reporting-database.html

Once the rebuild is done you have to change the reporting database connection string so that it uses the new updated database rather than the old one.

Doing this last step fixed it for me. The old database does not have a DeployDate column in the database and that was what caused the error.